# Can I call RequestDispatcher in a getter?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pojo, jspinclude

I have a framework based on JSP, and I want to move the logic from the JSP in Java, so for that I'm using a POJO with

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="myClass" scope="page"/> 
<c:set var="myVariable" scope="request" value="${myBean.myGetter}"/>
```

I have a reference to the request in `myClass`.
My question is if I can set some attributes on request, do a `RequestDispatcher.include` to a JSP that will use the attributes I set, when the call gets back, to use some attributes that were put on the request by the included JSP.

I used RequestDispatcher only in servlet/filter, but not on a POJO within a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have reference to `request`   you can do it. Ultimately, the `JSP` code is translated to `Servlet`, and calling include in `Bean` will be as same as calling it from code within `servlet`.

Comment: because of the signature of include method ?